# Write a brainfuck compiler

Tags: code-golf, brainfuck, compiler

Write a program that takes a brainfuck program and compiles it to executable machine code. You can target x86, x86_64, jvm (java bytecode) or armv6, and use one of the following executable formats: ELF, a.out, class file, exe, com. The executable should work in Linux or Windows (or Java on either).

Neither your program nor the generated executable may run any external program (such as another compiler, assembler or interpreter).

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting?

Comment: Any chance you have any sources for machine code?

This would be my first machine code golfing exercise if you happen to have any resources I could use as an example?

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio I don't have any particular resources, but generally you can start by looking into [assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) for your platform of choice, and assemble/disassemble some examples. Google is your friend :) A looong time ago I participated in a couple of [machine code golfing competitions](http://www.hugi.scene.org/compo/hcompo.htm), I didn't do very well but I remember we were using the com format for DOS, as it had no extra headers and stuff, just code. Maybe other people can give more links and suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## C, <s>866</s>  783 bytes

Since my code outputs 32 bit ELF executable I can't promise that it will work on everyones setup. It took enough tweaking to get the executable to stop segfaulting on my computer.

For anyone trying to run this:

```
$ uname --all
Linux 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

A Brainfuck program is read from stdin and the compiled ELF is written to stdout.

```
#define P *(t++)
#define C case
#define B break
char a[30000],b[65535],f,*t=b;*c[100];**d=c;main(g){P=188;t+=4;while((f=getchar())!=-1)switch(f){C'>':P=68;B;C'<':P=76;B;C'+':P=254;P=4;P=36;B;C'-':P=254;P=12;P=36;B;C'.':P=187;t+=4;P=137;P=225;P=186;P=1;t+=3;P=184;P=4;t+=3;P=205;P=128;B;C',':P=187;P=1;t+=3;P=137;P=225;P=186;P=1;t+=3;P=184;P=3;t+=3;P=205;P=128;B;C'[':P=138;P=4;P=36;P=133;P=192;P=15;P=132;t+=4;*d=(int*)t-1;d++;B;C']':P=138;P=4;P=36;P=133;P=192;P=15;P=133;t+=4;d--;g=((char*)(*d+1))-t;*((int*)t-1)=g;**d=-g;B;}P=184;P=1;t+=3;P=187;t+=4;P=205;P=128;*(int*)(b+1)=0x8048054+t-b;long long z[]={282579962709375,0,4295163906,223472812116,0,4297064500,4294967296,577727389698621440,36412867248128,30064779550,140720308490240};write(1,&z,84);write(1,b,t-b);write(1,a,30000);}
```

## Ungolfed

In the ungolfed version of the code, you can get a better idea of what's going on. The character array at the end of the golfed code is an encoding of the ELF and program header in the ungolfed code. This code also show how each Brainfuck instruction is translated into bytecode.

```
#include <linux/elf.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_BIN_LEN 65535
#define MAX_JUMPS 100

unsigned int org = 0x08048000;



unsigned char move_right[] = {0x44};                              /*inc   esp         */

unsigned char move_left[]  = {0x4c};                              /*dec   esp         */

unsigned char inc_cell[]   = {0xfe,0x04,0x24};                    /*inc   [esp]       */

unsigned char dec_cell[]   = {0xfe,0x0c,0x24};                    /*dec   [esp]       */

unsigned char read_char[]  = {0xbb,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,           /*mov   ebx,  0     */
                              0x89,0xe1,                          /*mov   ecx,  esp   */
                              0xba,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,           /*mov   edx,  1     */
                              0xb8,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,           /*mov   eax,  3     */
                              0xcd,0x80};                         /*int   0x80        */

unsigned char print_char[] = {0xbb,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,           /*mov   ebx,  1     */
                              0x89,0xe1,                          /*mov   ecx,  esp   */
                              0xba,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,           /*mov   edx,  1     */
                              0xb8,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,           /*mov   eax,  4     */
                              0xcd,0x80};                         /*int   0x80        */


unsigned char loop_start[] = {0x8a,0x04,0x24,                     /*mov   eax,  [esp] */
                              0x85,0xc0,                          /*test  eax,  eax   */
                              0x0f,0x84,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};     /*je    int32_t     */

unsigned char loop_end[]   = {0x8a,0x04,0x24,                     /*mov   eax,  [esp] */
                              0x85,0xc0,                          /*test  eax,  eax   */
                              0x0f,0x85,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};     /*jne   int32_t     */

unsigned char call_exit[]  = {0xb8,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,           /*mov   eax,  1     */
                              0xbb,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,           /*mov   ebx,  0     */
                              0xcd,0x80};                         /*int   0x80        */
unsigned char prelude[]    = {0xbc,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};          /*mov   esp, int32_t*/

unsigned char tape[100];

int main(){
    unsigned char text[MAX_BIN_LEN];
    unsigned char *txt_ptr = text;

    int32_t *loop_jmps[MAX_JUMPS];
    int32_t **loop_jmps_ptr = loop_jmps;

    Elf32_Off entry;

    entry = org + sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr) + 1 * sizeof(Elf32_Phdr);

    memcpy(txt_ptr,prelude,sizeof(prelude));
    txt_ptr += sizeof(prelude);
    char input;
    while((input = getchar()) != -1){
        switch(input){
            case '>':
                memcpy(txt_ptr,move_right,sizeof(move_right));
                txt_ptr += sizeof(move_right);
                break;
            case '<':
                memcpy(txt_ptr,move_left,sizeof(move_left));
                txt_ptr += sizeof(move_left);
                break;
            case '+':
                memcpy(txt_ptr,inc_cell,sizeof(inc_cell));
                txt_ptr += sizeof(inc_cell);
                break;
            case '-':
                memcpy(txt_ptr,dec_cell,sizeof(dec_cell));
                txt_ptr += sizeof(dec_cell);
                break;
            case '.':
                memcpy(txt_ptr,print_char,sizeof(print_char));
                txt_ptr += sizeof(print_char);
                break;
            case ',':
                memcpy(txt_ptr,read_char,sizeof(read_char));
                txt_ptr += sizeof(read_char);
                break;
            case '[':
                memcpy(txt_ptr,loop_start,sizeof(loop_start));
                txt_ptr += sizeof(loop_start);
                *loop_jmps_ptr = (int32_t*) txt_ptr - 1;
                loop_jmps_ptr++;
                break;
            case ']':
                memcpy(txt_ptr,loop_end,sizeof(loop_end));
                txt_ptr += sizeof(loop_end);
                loop_jmps_ptr--;
                int32_t offset = ((unsigned char*) (*loop_jmps_ptr + 1)) - txt_ptr;
                *((int32_t*)txt_ptr - 1) = offset;
                **loop_jmps_ptr = -offset;
                break;
        }
    }

    memcpy(txt_ptr,call_exit,sizeof(call_exit));
    txt_ptr += sizeof(call_exit);

    *(int32_t*)(text + 1) = entry + (txt_ptr - text);


    Elf32_Ehdr ehdr = {
        {0x7F,'E','L','F',ELFCLASS32,ELFDATA2LSB,EV_CURRENT,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        ET_EXEC,
        EM_386,
        EV_CURRENT,
        entry,
        sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr),
        0,
        0,
        sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr),
        sizeof(Elf32_Phdr),
        1,
        0,
        0,
        SHN_UNDEF,
    };

    Elf32_Phdr phdr = {
        PT_LOAD,
        0,
        org,
        org,
        sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr) + sizeof(Elf32_Phdr) + (txt_ptr - text),
        sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr) + sizeof(Elf32_Phdr) + (txt_ptr - text),
        PF_R | PF_X | PF_W,
        0x1000,
    };

    int out = open("a.out",O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY,S_IRWXU);
    write(out,&ehdr,sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr));
    write(out,&phdr,sizeof(Elf32_Phdr));

    write(out,text,txt_ptr-text);
    write(out,tape,sizeof(tape));
    close(out);
}
```

---

## Self Modifying BrainFuck

In order to save on bytes, the tape for my compiler isn't allocated in a `.bss` section or anything fancy like that. Instead, the tape is 30,000 null bytes written directly after the compiled byte code of the Brainfuck program. Knowing this, and being aware of what byte code is generated by my compiler means that you can generate or modify byte code at runtime. A simple illustration of this 'feature' is a Brainfuck program that sets its own exit value.

```
 <<<<<<+
```

The program goes off the left edge of the tape into the byte code to the point that the exit code is normally set 0. Incrementing this byte causes the exit code to be set to 1 instead of 0 when the program eventually exits. With persistence, this could be used to do system level programming in Brainfuck.

Comment: Nice; your code actually has 865 bytes (you don't need a newline at the end of the file). Also, you can merge char variable declarations. I wonder if that long array can be compressed too, as it has many zeros.

Comment: @aditsu I've been working on finding some better encoding for the header array. C doesn't come with any built in compression libraries so zipping it seems out of the question. The best I've come up with is encoding it as an array of `long long int` instead of `char`. There's definitely room for me to golf out some of my variable declarations. I'll see how much I can get there and update my answer.

Comment: I was thinking some form of RLE, but.. whatever works :)

Comment: you may replace '577727389698621440' by '4105*pow(2,47)' using implicit declaration of pow, for 4 bytes (this works with gcc, at least) ~

Comment: [612 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZAxbtswFIb3nMJQB5GUFDxapE2bYRevGbybHiRKSoUiTiATiIuihVvkAD1Bz9AxQLcOHTvkBukJcgP3UYJjdAggAj8f/@@9p99lV84dDm@qumk39WjJfJKcHW@LUdnVxXvtim195t4V3ahczaTM5Tpl3pSauRUHWGvGKuP0ddFuSEM/Lg1XSjc3HfGJEfozacxV7QNOKNV0e9fiJRgX8dt4vjQTpRfxRVDTCaokqLEUemnCyUMtO9X4@Fg8j@elu7n9QC6jXz/trixqrmYAlj8@2J0CVwFEqU/5jGpchM8QSU/I7/@QP68iq3i@9Z1DxqeXEbrkWIBQBSoBjYNosHLNqiQxpN14Rn3GkVy/TsqBTAeyyrI@woww8tKAGkJCZowS7MwpzTzVn0K2fQphaB6Emuo@ZswHZJ@P0mzoQkrkDOCPCQVSJD4r9V3X@prwfiExEU7IafP87f6LBQvPP/ZfLbdHv52IULW7MQDkAl@gP8M7nMTf@@/42enTfh@lStCXIWWKI5McLYC7Hw7/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: You do `inc esp` and then `inc [esp]`. Shouldn't it be either `inc esp; inc byte [esp]` or `add esp, 4; inc [esp]`?

Comment: @xiver77 The emitted code is correct (opcode `0xfe`), but you're right that the mnemonic in the comment should be `inc byte [esp]`.

Answer (score 13):

### Python, 1974 chars

```
import sys
s='\x11\x75\x30\xbc\x08\x4b\x03\x3c'
k=[]
for c in sys.stdin.read():
 if'>'==c:s+='\x84\x01\x01'
 if'<'==c:s+='\x84\x01\xff'
 if'+'==c:s+='\x2a\x1b\x5c\x33\x04\x60\x91\x54'
 if'-'==c:s+='\x2a\x1b\x5c\x33\x04\x64\x91\x54'
 if'['==c:k+=[len(s)];s+='\x2a\x1b\x33\x99\x00\x00'
 if']'==c:a=k[-1];k=k[:-1];d=len(s)-a;s=s[:a+4]+'%c%c'%(d>>8,d&255)+s[a+6:]+'\xa7%c%c'%(-d>>8&255,-d&255)
 if','==c:s+='\x2a\x1b\xb2\x00\x02\xb6\x00\x03\x91\x54'
 if'.'==c:s+='\xb2\x00\x04\x59\x2a\x1b\x33\xb6\x00\x05\xb6\x00\x06'
s+='\xb1'
n=len(s)
sys.stdout.write('\xca\xfe\xba\xbe\x00\x03\x00-\x00+\n\x00\x08\x00\x13\t\x00\x14\x00\x15\n\x00\x16\x00\x17\t\x00\x14\x00\x18\n\x00\x19\x00\x1a\n\x00\x19\x00\x1b\x07\x00\x1c\x07\x00\x1d\x01\x00\x06<init>\x01\x00\x03()V\x01\x00\x04Code\x01\x00\x0fLineNumberTable\x01\x00\x04main\x01\x00\x16([Ljava/lang/String;)V\x01\x00\nExceptions\x07\x00\x1e\x01\x00\nSourceFile\x01\x00\x06B.java\x0c\x00\t\x00\n\x07\x00\x1f\x0c\x00 \x00!\x07\x00"\x0c\x00#\x00$\x0c\x00%\x00&\x07\x00\'\x0c\x00(\x00)\x0c\x00*\x00\n\x01\x00\x01B\x01\x00\x10java/lang/Object\x01\x00\x13java/io/IOException\x01\x00\x10java/lang/System\x01\x00\x02in\x01\x00\x15Ljava/io/InputStream;\x01\x00\x13java/io/InputStream\x01\x00\x04read\x01\x00\x03()I\x01\x00\x03out\x01\x00\x15Ljava/io/PrintStream;\x01\x00\x13java/io/PrintStream\x01\x00\x05write\x01\x00\x04(I)V\x01\x00\x05flush\x00!\x00\x07\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\t\x00\n\x00\x01\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05*\xb7\x00\x01\xb1\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\t\x00\r\x00\x0e\x00\x02\x00\x0b\x00\x00'+'%c%c'%((n+60)>>8,(n+60)&255)+'\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x00'+'%c%c'%(n>>8,n&255)+s+'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00*\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\t\x00\x0b\x00\x0b\x00\x13\x00\r\x00\x1d\x00\x0f\x00&\x00\x11\x00,\x00\x12\x002\x00\x14\x008\x00\x15\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x10\x00\x01\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x12')
```

Below are the translations to java bytecode.  local 0 is a byte array representing the tape, local 1 is the data pointer.

```
>  iinc 1,+1
<  iinc 1,-1
+  aload_0;iload_1;dup2;baload;iconst_1;iadd;i2b;bastore
-  aload_0;iload_1;dup2;baload;iconst_1;isub;i2b;bastore
[  aload_0;iload_1;baload;ifeq xx xx
]  goto xx xx
,  aload_0;iload_1;getstatic #2;invokevirtual #3;i2b;bastore
.  getstatic #4;dup;aload_0;iload_1;baload;invokevirtual #5;invokevirtual #6
```

The `xx xx` are offsets to reach the matching bracket.  #2 is `System.in`, #3 is `read()`, #4 is `System.out`, #5 is `write()`, and #6 is `flush()`.

The preamble allocates a 30000 byte array and initializes the tape position to 0.

The giant wrapper at the end was generated by compiling a dummy `B.java` file with code for one of each opcode (to induce generation of the correct constant tables and other junk), then performing delicate surgery on it.

Run it like

```
python bfc.py < input.b > B.class
java B
```

Disassemble with

```
javap -c B
```

I'm sure it could be golfed some more.  I'm just happy it works...

Comment: Use from sys import* and then shave off 2 chars by removing both sys.

Comment: You could use base64 to encode that binary data and shave off some bytes

Answer (score 3):

### 16-bit x86 assembly code, 104 bytes

This code is from 2014, but I just found the task.

```
;compliant version, non-commands are ignored, but 104 bytes long

[bits 16]  
[org 0x100]  
; assume bp=091e used  
; assume di=fffe  
; assume si=0100  
; assume dx=cs (see here)  
; assume cx=00ff  
; assume bx=0000  
; assume ax=0000 used (ah)  
; assume sp=fffe  
start:
        mov al, code_nothing - start  
code_start:
        mov ch, 0x7f ; allow bigger programs  
        mov bx, cx  
        mov di, cx  
        rep stosb  
        mov bp, find_right + start - code_start ;cache loop head for smaller compiled programs  
        jmp code_start_end  
find_right:
        pop si  
        dec si  
        dec si ;point to loop head  
        cmp [bx], cl  
        jne loop_right_end  
loop_right:
        lodsb  
        cmp al, 0xD5 ; the "bp" part of "call bp" (because 0xFF is not unique, watch for additional '[')  
        jne loop_left  
        inc cx  
loop_left:
        cmp al, 0xC3 ; ret (watch for ']')  
        jne loop_right  
        loop loop_right ;all brackets matched when cx==0  
        db 0x3c ;cmp al, xx (mask push)  
loop_right_end:
        push si  
        lodsw ; skip "call" or dummy "dec" instruction, depending on context  
        push si  
code_sqright:
        ret  
code_dec:
        dec byte [bx]  
code_start_end:
        db '$' ;end DOS string, also "and al, xx"  
code_inc:
        inc byte [bx]  
        db '$'  
code_right:
        inc bx ;al -> 2  
code_nothing:
        db '$'  
code_left:
        dec bx  
        db '$'  
code_sqleft:
        call bp  
        db '$'  
; create lookup table  
real_start:
        inc byte [bx+'<'] ;point to code_left  
        dec byte [bx+'>'] ;point to code_right  
        mov byte [bx+'['], code_sqleft - start  
        mov byte [bx+']'], code_sqright - start  
        lea sp, [bx+45+2] ;'+' + 4 (2b='+', 2c=',', 2d='-', 2e='.')  
        push (code_dec - start) + (code_dot - start) * 256  
        push (code_inc - start) + (code_comma - start) * 256  
pre_write:
        mov ah, code_start >> 8  
        xchg dx, ax  
; write  
        mov ah, 9  
        int 0x21  
; read  
code_comma:
        mov dl, 0xff  
        db 0x3d ; cmp ax, xxxx (mask mov)  
code_dot:
        mov dl, [bx]  
        mov ah, 6  
        int 0x21  
        mov [bx], al  
        db '$'  
        db 0xff ; parameter for '$', doubles as test for zero  
; switch  
        xlatb  
        jne pre_write  
  ; next two lines can also be removed  
  ; if the program ends with extra ']'  
  ; and then we are at 100 bytes... :-)  
the_end:
        mov dl, 0xC3  
        int 0x21  
        int 0x20
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not an [interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149105/7416)?

Comment: No, it's absolutely a compiler.  "bf.com < hello.bf > out.com", then out.com will be executable.

Comment: Ok, can you please explain how to compile it and what OS it works in? I haven't been able to run it yet.

Comment: assemble with YASM, run in MS-DOS (via DOSBox is okay).

Comment: Ok, I tried it (`bf.com < hello.bf > out.com`), it took a long time, and generated a 19MB OUT.COM, which freezes when I run it. It seems that your code just outputs random junk.

Comment: I found your code on [github](https://github.com/peterferrie/brainfuck/blob/master/brainfuck.asm), it looks like something happened to lines 63-64 when you copied and pasted it (it probably got treated as html). That code also seems to output very large quantities of random junk, but this new junk managed to print "Hello World!" before freezing.

Comment: Anyway, even if you fix these problems, your program doesn't really qualify because one of the requirements is: "The executable should work in Linux or Windows (or Java on either)."

Comment: The '<' and '>' need to be escaped.  Anyway, 32-bit Windows has a DOS console where will run, and "com" is explicitly one of the allowed formats.

Comment: Oh, you should have said that earlier. It behaves much better in (32-bit) windoze - it doesn't add tons of random junk and the generated program terminates nicely (at least the Hello World example). However, I tried the [prime example](https://github.com/fabianishere/brainfuck/blob/master/examples/prime.bf) and it doesn't seem to take input, is there something I need to do?