# One source, lots of Brainfuck

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, brainfuck

Write a Brainfuck interpreter that can interpret multiple Brainfuck programs embedded within the same source.  The syntax is the same except that the instructions must be prefixxed with the number/ID of the targetted program.  Example:

1st program

```
+++[->+<]
```

2nd program

```
+>++>+++.
```

Mashup

```
1+1+1+2+2>1[1-2+2+2>1>1+2+1<2+1]2+2.
```

What is required:

- That it is theoretically able to interpret an unlimited number programs embedded within the same source.
- That the instruction order does not matter.
- That the code does not use features of a language that would natively solve this problem or natively interpret Brainfuck.  Pretty much, don't cheat.  I'll leave this to your discretion.

What is not:

- Unlimited Brainfuck storage.  Only a minimum of 1000 Brainfuck cells per is imposed.
- It is not required that the input and output specify which bf program is doing the io.  It'd be a cool feature tho, so if you do implement this you get -15 bytes.

You can do postfix if you want, just specify in that case.  This is **code-golf**, so the smallest source in bytes (after the the -15 byte bonus) wins.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how input/output is handled?

Comment: shelvacu: It's the brainfuck io that I was referring to.

Comment: How will answers be scored? [tag:code-golf], [tag:popularity-context], or [tag:code-challenge]? Based on the mention of byte-count bonuses, I'm guessing [tag:code-golf], but please tag it as such.

Comment: Are the ID's only numeric?

Comment: This is a relatively minor transformation of  [Interpret Brainfuck](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck), and in my opinion is close enough to count as a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with @PeterTaylor. In practice, you only need to split the input into the groups. The rest is a normal interpreter. Not sure this is really that much of a difference.

Comment: I thought it was distinct enough, but fair enough.