# Convert Brainfuck to a Non-Golfing Language

Tags: code-golf, brainfuck, code-generation

#### Input:

**Any** Brainfuck program. This includes brainfuck programs with comments such as `+++COMMENT[>+++<-].`.

#### Output:

A program in one of the below languages that produces the same output as the Brainfuck program on **all inputs**. It should produce the same output exactly as the [interepreter on this website](http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html) There are no [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) or performance restrictions on the **output program**; the outputted program doesn't need to be optimized in any way. In other words, the quality of the outputted program does not affect score, only the translation program. To clarify: you may write **your answer** in any language that is normally valid for answers on PCG. The restriction on output languages is **only for the outputted program.**

The outputted program **only receives the same input that would be received by the Brainfuck** program. The outputted program **does not receive the Brainfuck program as input**.

#### Valid Output Languages

- C#
- C++
- C
- Java 8
- Javascript ES6 (it is both okay to receive all of stdin in a single prompt, or multiple prompts per character)
- Perl
- Python 2.7
- Python 3.4.2
- Ruby

#### Fine Print

You may write a [program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/17249) which takes the Brainfuck program as a String argument or on STDIN or closest alternative, and which [returns the output as a String or printing it to STDOUT (or closest alternative).](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) You may optionally include a single trailing newline in the output.

Additionally, [standard loopholes which are no longer funny](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) are **banned**. You may not use external libraries or external data files, the code must be self contained.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest program wins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interpret Brainfuck](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck)

Comment: It's not a dup, as a compiler is not an interpreter

Comment: It might not be a dup, but the question is whether there is a shorter solution than copy&pasting a golfed interpreter in one of the allowed languages; and copying the brainfuck to the output program.

Comment: Can you clarify the behavior of the linked interpreter? What is the max number of memory cells? How is overflow of cell values handled?

Comment: @nderscore The linked interpreter uses signed integers that wrap around from -128 to +127.  However, the values are effectively cast to 2-byte unsigned ints before being output as characters; so -1 => chr(65535) ().  Personally, I would prefer output in the form of 1-byte (ASCII) characters (in part because that's what my solution uses).  The tape is circular, with 32768 cells.  durron597, are these specs what you intended?

Comment: Any reason not to open this up to all output languages?

Comment: I agree with Adám - there are tons of non-golfing languages out there that you're keeping from participating here. Also, why those very specific versions of Python and Java?

Comment: @Adám `,[.,]` To convert Brainfuck to the output language Brainfuck in Brainfuck.

Comment: AFAIK: None of the mentioned languages can support this, reason: Memory. Brainfuck has an infinite amount of memory, but the listed languages have a finite amount (at least their implementation does). For example C, while you can create a implementation that supports an arbitary amount of memory, it still isn't infinite since `CHAR_BIT * 2 ** ( CHAR_BIT*sizeof(size_t))  ` is an absolute maximum amount of bits it can use and a implementation has to define this values. Maybe it would help when you define a minimum maximum number of cells and a minimum maximum value for a single cell?

Answer (score 5):

## K, <s>143</s> <s>129</s> 113 bytes

```
1!"}int a[99];int*p=a;main(){",,/{("p++;";"p--;";"*p++;";"*p--;";"*p=getchar();if(*p<0)*p=0;";"putchar(*p);";"while(*p){";"}";"")"><+-,.[]"?x}'
```

This is an extremely straightforward approach which generates C source code by emitting a preamble, a C snippet for each BF command and then a postscript. Non-BF characters are translated into empty strings in the concatenated output.

The translation into C is as follows:

- preamble: `int a[99];int*p=a;main(){`
- `>`: `p++;`
- `<`: `p--;`
- `+`: `*p++;`
- `-`: `*p--;`
- `,`: `*p=getchar();if(*p<0)*p=0;`
- `.`: `putchar(*p);`
- `[`: `while(*p){`
- `]`: `}`
- postscript: `}`

I suspect that there is room for improvement here by using more mangled abuses of C or compressing the C fragments.

The K part of the program by itself would look like the following, where `c` is the C translations of each BF instruction and `p` is the preamble/postscript:

```
1!p,,/{c"><+-,.[]"?x}'
```

Using the venerable BF string reverser program `>,[>,]<[.<]` as my test case I generate code which looks like the following after a bit of whitespace for readability:

```
int a[99];
int*p=a;

main(){
    p++;
    *p=getchar();if(*p<0)*p=0;
    while(*p){
        p++;
        *p=getchar();if(*p<0)*p=0;
    }
    p--;
    while(*p){
        putchar(*p);
        p--;
    }
}
```

### edit:

A few tweaks. Firstly, more compliant tape declaration as suggested by alexander-brett. The `int` part can be left off:

`int a[99];` -> `a[1<<15];` (-1 byte)

Also, it seems that EOF behavior in BF can return 0, -1 or cause no change as a result of `,`. EOF=-1 seems to be what other solutions are going with, so for the sake of uniformity I will do the same:

`*p=getchar();if(*p<0)*p=0;` -> `*p=getchar();` (-13 bytes)

Note that this means my string reverser program will choke if you simply cat it a file ending in EOF(!), but as above it seems to be fair.

The new complete 129 byte solution:

```
1!"}a[1<<15];int*p=a;main(){",,/{("p++;";"p--;";"*p++;";"*p--;";"*p=getchar();";"putchar(*p);";"while(*p){";"}";"")"><+-,.[]"?x}'
```

### edit 2, much, much later:

I randomly stumbled upon this old answer and, being older and wiser, realized there are several ways to make this shorter:

- exploit the fact that it's completely syntactically valid C to include semicolons after *every* fragment instead of just those who need them, and thus remove them from the lookup table entries.
- use the k5/k6 or [oK](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html) dialects, which have overloads for `\` and `/` which split a string apart on a character or join a list of strings with a character, respectively, to use a more compact representation of the lookup table and accomplish the above.
- take advantage of the fact that find (dyadic `?`) in the above dialects naturally conforms to a listy right argument, and thus does not need an explicit lambda + each

The one downside is that in these dialects there is no "rotate" primitive, so we have to add the `"}"` suffix in a less elegant manner. The overall structure of our solution:

```
1!     p, ,/{c"><+-,.[]"?x}'   / old
,[;"}"]p,";"/c"><+-,.[]"?      / new
```

The complete (and now totally points-free!) solution:

```
,[;"}"]"a[1<<15];int*p=a;main(){",";"/("|"\"p++|p--|*p++|*p--|*p=getchar()|putchar(*p)|while(*p){|}|")"><+-,.[]"?
```

Which shaves us down to 113 bytes.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a[30000]?

Comment: That would be more compliant. `a[1<<15]` is closer to the interpreter above, and I can leave off "int" as C variables are implicitly ints. It also looks like my "EOF=0" handling is more than is strictly necessary, even if it's a common assumption.

Comment: DARN! You beat me to K. :)

Comment: Unary postfix binds first over unary prefix, so [`*p++` increments `p` rather than `*p`. `++*p` works as intended.](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEIDh/Z7iKAhtUokUt6OTj6EdYjw1YC9HiC6lz57a7f@GPxxfIdQapeDso7TdAnv76zCNy9CfV9ptdPQEzllrlMCotYTO4SXN6jNjSVjejP6efoyfKAya/9ezbQ6PmzQ9Gu0IMpdvFjwRrLVu)

Comment: Suggest `*p*=read(0,p,1);` instead of `*p=getchar();if(*p<0)*p=0;`

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (*ES7 Draft*), 170 bytes

Function which compiles BF source code into Javascript. The resulting code accepts input via `prompt()` and outputs via `alert()`, both one character at a time.

```js
f=x=>'x=[i=0];'+[for(y of x)'z=x[i]|=0,x[i]'+'0++0--0,i++0,i--0,alert(String.fromCharCode(z))0=prompt().charCodeAt()0;for(;x[i];){x0}x'.split(0)['+-><.,[]'.indexOf(y)+1]]
```

The result is composed of:

Preamble: `x=[i=0];` - Initializes `x` as an object to store memory cells and `i` as `0` for the initial index.

Each command is prefixed with: `z=x[i]|=0,x[i]` - Forces undefined memory cells to 0, starts all commands with `x[i]` to reduce repetition in the translation map. Stores value at current index in `z`.

Each command is also seperated by `,` commas due to implicit casting of the array to a string.

Command translation map:

- `(unknown)` => empty string
- `+` => `++` - increment value at `x[i]`
- `-` => `--` - decrement value at `x[i]`
- `>` => `,i++` - increment index pointer `i`
- `<` => `,i--` - decrement index pointer `i`
- `.` => `,alert(String.fromCharCode(z))` - alert character from value at `x[i]`
- `,` => `=prompt().charCodeAt()` - store converted character code from prompt at `x[i]`
- `[` => `;for(;x[i];){x` - Loop while value at `x[i]` is truthy (non-zero).
- `]` => `}x` - End loop. Unused x appended to prevent errors from commas.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>250</s> 244 bytes

```
def B(b):
 I=0;print"from ctypes import*;R,p,c=[0]*9999,0,CDLL('libc.so.6')"
 for c in b:
     try:print' '*I+'p+=1|p-=1|R[p]+=1|R[p]-=1|c.putchar(R[p])|R[p]=c.getchar()|while R[p]!=0:|'.split('|')['><+-.,[]'.index(c)];I+=']&['.index(c)-1
     except:0

#first indentation level=space, 2nd indentation level=tab
```

(thks to @undergroundmonorail for helping me save 4 extra bytes)

The B function takes bf code as parameter and generates... a Python script.

Brainfuck's "tape" is seen a an array called R, which owns <s>32768</s> 9999 items, and the pointer is stored in a variable called p.

The lack of a native equivalent to C's getchar function in python forced me to load it using ctypes at runtime, which makes the generated script unusable on Windows (untested, I guess that a Windows version should load mscvrt.dll instead of libc.so.6)

### Example

The infamous 'hello world':

```
B('++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.')
```

Generates the following script:

```
from ctypes import*;R,p,c=[0]*9999,0,CDLL('libc.so.6')
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
while R[p]!=0:
 p+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 p+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 p+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 R[p]+=1
 p+=1
 R[p]+=1
 p-=1
 p-=1
 p-=1
 p-=1
 R[p]-=1

p+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
p+=1
R[p]+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
c.putchar(R[p])
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
p+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
p-=1
p-=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
p+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
R[p]+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
c.putchar(R[p])
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
R[p]-=1
c.putchar(R[p])
p+=1
R[p]+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
p+=1
c.putchar(R[p])
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the length of `R` is `0xfff`=4095, not 32768. Also you can save some bytes by changing the last line to `except:0`. `0` is a no-op and 3 bytes shorter than `pass`.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Array_size

Comment: You can save a few bytes by replacing `from ctypes import*` with `from msvcrt import*` and using just `putchar` instead of `c.putchar`.

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp &  JavaScript - 425 bytes

**N.B.** *I am using the [Parenscript](https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/) library, so this is just for the fun.*

```
(defun b(i &aux(s(coerce i'list)))(labels((c()(do(r x)((or x(not s))(reverse r))(push(case(pop s)(#\>`(incf p))(#\<`(decf p))(#\+`(setf(aref a p)(1+#1=(or(aref a p)0))))(#\-`(setf(aref a p)(1- #1#)))(#\.`((ps:@ console log)((ps:@ *String from-char-code)#1#)))(#\,`(setf(aref a p)((ps:@(prompt)char-code-at)0)))(#\[`(loop until(= 0 #1#)do ,@(c))))(#\](setf x t)(go /))(t(go /)))r)/)))(ps:ps*`(let((a(make-array))(p 0)),@(c)))))
```

## Ungolfed

```lisp
(defun bf(i)
  (let ((s (coerce i'list)))
    (labels((lbf ()
              (do(r x)((or x(not s))(reverse r))
                      (push (case (pop s)
                              (#\> `(incf p))
                              (#\< `(decf p))
                              (#\+ `(setf(aref a p)(1+(or (aref a p)0))))
                              (#\- `(setf(aref a p)(1-(or (aref a p)0))))
                              (#\. `((ps:@ console log)((ps:@ *String from-char-code) (or(aref a p)0))))
                              (#\, `(setf(aref a p) ((ps:@ (prompt) char-code-at) 0)))
                              (#\[ `(loop until(= 0(or(aref a p)0))do ,@(lbf)))
                              (#\] (setf x t) (go /))
                              (t (go /)))
                            r)/)))
      `(let ((a (make-array))
             (p 0))
         ,@(lbf)))))
```

## Explanations

- Convert input string as list of characters `s`
- The recursive function `lbf` pop elements from `s` and build a local list of expressions `r`
- Whenever we encounter a `[` character, the function recurse in order to create a nested block of instructions
- Whenever we encounter a `]` character, the function exits, returning to one higher level of invocation. Note that when returning from the function, the variable `s` has been modified to hold the rest of the characters to be processed, thanks to `pop`.
- The whole S-expr being built is expressed in a sub-language of Common Lisp that can be converted to Javascript thanks to Parenscript.

## Optimized version

I made a [slightly optimized version](http://pastebin.com/5Y7Wrnbs) that is too long to post here, with the following changes:

- Parsing only produces an AST containing the following symbols: `print`, `read`, `left`, `right`, `inc`, `dec`, `bracketed` (nested tree) and `brainfuck` (root tree).
- The AST is analyzed to group all increment and decrement operations, as well as move operations, in order to build `(add x)` and `(move y)` terms.
- Finally, the AST is converted into Parenscript code.
- That code is emitted as a Javascript string

The resulting Javascript for Hello World is:

```js
(function () {
   var a = new Array();
   var p = 0;
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 10;
   while (0 !== (a[p] || 0)) {
       ++p;
       a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 7;
       ++p;
       a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 10;
       ++p;
       a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 3;
       ++p;
       a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 1;
       p += -4;
       a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + -1;
   };
   ++p;
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 2;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   ++p;
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 1;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 7;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 3;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   ++p;
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 2;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   p += -2;
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 15;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   ++p;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 3;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + -6;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + -8;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   ++p;
   a[p] = (a[p] || 0) + 1;
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
   ++p;
   return console.log(String.fromCharCode(a[p] || 0));
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), <s>106</s> <s>100</s> 99 bytes

**Edit:** finally below 100 bytes! -1 thanks to ceilingcat (`⌈,`)

Creates C code.

```apl
^
>
<
[+-]
\.
,
\[
]|$
a[1<<15];*p=a;main(){
p++;
p--;
&&*p;
putchar(*p);
read(0,p,1);
while(*p){
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLCsIwFEbh@b8OKWkexQwc5ZqNpBEuttCCyjVYHLRde6yz8533wkOp9YYIQjIuo@9g0Sfk7QROnshfctBy5fDk@aXaFWJMgDgX0DRajlw@94mL0tIGlJEHdbZi/YHvND/G/1@x1xptijZT6ij/AA)

The first nine lines are PCRE regexes. Matches throughout the input are replaced with the corresponding string from the last 9 lines. The only noteworthy "hacks" are transpiling `[+-]` to `&&*p;` where `&` means the matched plus/minus symbol, and combining end-of-loop with end-of-main through mapping `]|$` to `}`

Comment: Unary postfix binds first over unary prefix, so [`*p++` increments `p` rather than `*p`. `++*p` works as intended.](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEIDh/Z7iKAhtUokUt6OTj6EdYjw1YC9HiC6lz57a7f@GPxxfIdQapeDso7TdAnv76zCNy9CfV9ptdPQEzllrlMCotYTO4SXN6jNjSVjejP6efoyfKAya/9ezbQ6PmzQ9Gu0IMpdvFjwRrLVu)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>127</s> 120B + 2

```
%h=qw#> ++p;
< --p;
+ ++*p;
- --*p;
. putchar(*p);
, *p=getchar();
[ while(*p){
] }#;say"a[1<<15],*p=a;main(){@h{/./g}}"
```

The magic happens in `@h{/./g}`: `/./g` splits the input into characters, `@h{}` is a hash slice, and the `""` interpolation joins hash elements using a space (by default). The target is C using exactly the spec on the Brainfuck website. 2 point penalty for -0n: run with

```
perl -M5.10.0 -0n scratch.pl > test.c < input.bf && gcc -ansi test.c && ./a.out
```

7B saving thanks to CL- and the prevailing opinion on variable declarations.

Comment: It looks like you can shorten the C preamble from `main(){int a[1<<15];int*p=a;` to `a[1<<15],*p=a;main(){` for a 7 byte saving. This also guarantees that each element of `a` will be initialised to 0.

Comment: @CL- how do I compile that? gcc on OSX errors if I don't put a type in

Comment: You'll see a warning, but it should still compile fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 214 bytes

Outputs Ruby 1.9 code.

```
[^+\-[\]<>.,]/
\[/while tape[i
\]/end;
\[i/[i] != 0 do 
\./print tape[i].chr;
if !defined?tape then require "io\x2Fconsole";tape=[0]*9999;i=0;end;
\+/tape[i]+=1;
-/tape[i]-=1;
</i+=1;
>/i-=1;
,/tape[i]=STDIN.getch;
```

[Try it here!](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%5B%5E%2B%5C-%5B%5C%5D%3C%3E.%2C%5D%2F%0A%5C%5B%2Fwhile%20tape%5Bi%0A%5C%5D%2Fend%3B%0A%5C%5Bi%2F%5Bi%5D%20!%3D%200%20do%20%0A%5C.%2Fprint%20tape%5Bi%5D.chr%3B%0Aif%20!defined%3Ftape%20then%20require%20%22io%5Cx2Fconsole%22%3Btape%3D%5B0%5D*9999%3Bi%3D0%3Bend%3B%0A%5C%2B%2Ftape%5Bi%5D%2B%3D1%3B%0A-%2Ftape%5Bi%5D-%3D1%3B%0A%3C%2Fi%2B%3D1%3B%0A%3E%2Fi-%3D1%3B%0A%2C%2Ftape%5Bi%5D%3DSTDIN.getch%3B%0A&input=%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%5B%3E%2B%2B%2B%2B%5B%3E%2B%2B%3E%2B%2B%2B%3E%2B%2B%2B%3E%2B%3C%3C%3C%3C-%5D%3E%2B%3E%2B%3E-%3E%3E%2B%5B%3C%5D%3C-%5D%3E%3E.%3E---.%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B..%2B%2B%2B.%3E%3E.%3C-.%3C.%2B%2B%2B.------.--------.%3E%3E%2B.%3E%2B%2B.%0A)

### Sample runs

#### Hello, world!

Input:

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
```

Output:

```
if !defined?tape then require "io\x2Fconsole";tape=[0]*9999;i=0;end;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;while tape[i] != 0 do i-=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;while tape[i] != 0 do i-=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;i-=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;i-=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;i-=1;tape[i]+=1;i+=1;i+=1;i+=1;i+=1;tape[i]-=1;end;i-=1;tape[i]+=1;i-=1;tape[i]+=1;i-=1;tape[i]-=1;i-=1;i-=1;tape[i]+=1;while tape[i] != 0 do i+=1;end;i+=1;tape[i]-=1;end;i-=1;i-=1;print tape[i].chr;i-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;print tape[i].chr;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;print tape[i].chr;print tape[i].chr;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;print tape[i].chr;i-=1;i-=1;print tape[i].chr;i+=1;tape[i]-=1;print tape[i].chr;i+=1;print tape[i].chr;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;print tape[i].chr;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;print tape[i].chr;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;tape[i]-=1;print tape[i].chr;i-=1;i-=1;tape[i]+=1;print tape[i].chr;i-=1;tape[i]+=1;tape[i]+=1;print tape[i].chr;
```

#### Mandelbrot

Input:

```
      A mandelbrot set fractal viewer in brainf*** written by Erik Bosman
+++++++++++++[->++>>>+++++>++>+<<<<<<]>>>>>++++++>--->>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[
>>>>>>>>>]+[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>>>>>>[-]>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-]+
<<<<<<<+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+[>>>>>>[>>>>>>>[-]>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>
>>>>>[-]+<<<<<<++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>+<<<<<<+++++++[-[->>>
>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[[-]>>>>>>[>>>>>
>>[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>
[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<
<<]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[
>>>>>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[
>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>[
-<<+>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<
<<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<
[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>
>>>>[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+
<<<<<<[->>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>
>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<
+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<
<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>
>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<[<<<<<<
<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<
<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->
>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<
<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<[->+>>>-<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++++++
+++++++>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<[-]<<]>>[<<<<<<<+<[-<+>>>>+<<[-]]>[-<<[->+>>>-
<<<<]>>>]>>>>>>>>>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>>>>>>[>>>>>
[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>[-<<<<<<<<
<+>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]+>[-
]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<
<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<[->>[-<<+>>]<
<[->>+>+<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>
>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>
[-<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>]<<[->>+<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<
<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>+>>>>>>>>
]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<[->>[-<<+
>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>
[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-
]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>
[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>++++++++
+++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+
>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[
-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>+>[-<-<<<<+>>>>>]>[-<<<<<<[->>>>>+<++<<<<]>>>>>[-<
<<<<+>>>>>]<->+>]<[->+<]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<]>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<
[->>>>->>>>>[>>[-<<->>]+<<[->>->[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]
+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>-<[-<<+>>]<<[->>+<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<
<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<
[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<
<<<+<[>[->>>>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]<]>[->>>-<<<<<<<<<
<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>>+<<<]<<
<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>[-<->]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<
<<<<<+<[>[->>>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>[->>>>+<<<<]>]<[->>>>-<<<<<<<
<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]<]>>[->>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[->>>>+<<<<
]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>+<<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<
[>[->>>>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]<]>[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>>+<<<]<<<<<<<
<<<<<]]>[-]>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-<
<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[
[>>>>>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+
[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>
[-<<+>>]<<[->>+>+<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<
<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[
>[-]<->>>[-<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>]<<[->>+<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[
>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>
>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>[-]>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<
<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<
<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-
<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>
>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>>>
[-<<<->>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->+>[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>[-<<
+>>]<]>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>]<<<]>>[-<+>>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>
[-<<+>>]<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>
>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->+>>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[-<+>]>]<[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>
>>>>>>>]<<]>>>[-<<+>[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[-<+>]<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>+<<<<<
]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>>>>>>[-<<<<<
<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>+>[-<-<<<<+>>>>
>]>>[-<<<<<<<[->>>>>+<++<<<<]>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<->+>>]<<[->>+<<]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<
<<<]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>->>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>-<[-<<+>>]<<[->>+<<
<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>[-<<->>]+<<[->>->[-<<<+>>>]<
<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<
<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>[-<->]<[->+
<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->>>>+<<[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]>]<[->>>-
<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]<]>>[->>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[->>>+<<<
]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>[-]>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>
>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-
<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>+<<]<]>[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>+<<[
->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>[-]<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>
>>]<<<<[->>>>+>[-]>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>
>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>+<<]<]>[->>-<<<<<<<<
<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>+<<[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<
<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>>>>[-<<<<+
>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>
]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>
>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>+>>
>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>[-<<+
>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>
[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-
]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>
[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<
<<[->>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>
>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<+>>>
>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+
<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>
>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<[<<<<<<<<<]
>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<
]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<
<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>
>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>->>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<[-]<<]>>]<<+>>>>[-<<<<
->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<.>>]>>>>[-<<<<<<<.>>>>>>>]<<<[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>[
>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<
[<<<<<<<<<]>+++++++++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>+>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<
<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+[-]>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<
<<<<[>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>[-]+>>>]<<<<
<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+>>[>+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]<<<<[->>>
>+<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<+<<<<<<<[>>>>>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<
<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<<+>>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<]<
+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>-<<<<[-]+<<<]+>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<->>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>->>[>>
>>>[->>+<<]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<<+>>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>]<<
<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>+<<<
<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-<<<<<->>>>>]+<<<<<[->>>>>->>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<
<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>>>>[-<
<<<<<<->>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>-<<[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<
<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<
<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>-<<<<<[<<<<<<<
<<]]>>>]<<<<.>>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>++++++++++[-[->>>>>>>>
>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>+>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<
<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+[-]>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>
>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-]+>>]<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<
<<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+>[>+>>>>>[-<<<<<->>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<]>>>>>>
>>]<+<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<-
>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<+>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<
<<<]>>>>>>>>-<<<<<[-]+<<<]+>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>->[>>>
>>>[->>+<<]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<+>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<
<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>
+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<<<<<<->>>>>>]+<
<<<<<[->>>>>>->>[-<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<
<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>
-<<[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>
>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<++++
+[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-<<<<<<[<<<<
<<<<<]]>>>]
```

Output (I'm glad it isn't scored!) is [available on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/w3X1SqNf) because it was too long to put here!

Comment: Yes! A ruby transpiler!

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>202</s> <s>196</s> 192 bytes

Outputs C code. Tested with Node.js 14.7.0 and GCC 10.1.0.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HY7NbsIwEITvfYpoTzb@gR5pcKRe@gIcoxysxAEjY7u2oUSBZ083nObT7M7sXvRd5z7ZWIQPg1mWUVnVgG73@66@ausJna0vm6h0Dew7JT3JmEIJZYpGXnWUvXaOWP5QDZmhgS@IjAGHw0pCIDEkxjYRUSAK8cYW8e9snSGbSGc0OjReqBw1GT2QHY/8kz6fuKB2FH25Vt5Kf9ZpDcGLto@OykvAL6EGyjBfL33wuVRjrlSVzO/NJkNgzEDrD2dKZT024GjMcj3ygw8cJ98T2A7mvs1lsB6oLOFYkvUngqm1LzgjXTiRkbzzlNYLbyXv/gE)

```
f=i=>"a[99];main(){int*p=a;"+Array.prototype.map.call(i,x=>({">":"p++","<":"p--","+":"++*p","-":"--*p","[":"while(*p){","]":"}",",":"read(0,p,1)||(*p=0)",".":"putchar(*p)"})[x]).join(";")+"}";
```

The only clever thing here is using `Array.map` on a string rather than an array. I expected this to be golfier than it was; the 24 characters for `Array.prototype.map.call` were brutal.

I copied some of the C code from nderscore's answer. As far as I can tell, the C is as golfed as it can be, other than perhaps the preamble. Potentially I could tease out some undefined behaviour to point `p` to somewhere lower down on the stack for fewer bytes than defining an array outright.

-6 bytes: replace `*p=getchar();if(*p<0)*p=0` with `read(0,p,1)||(*p=0)`. Thanks to ceilingcat
-4 bytes: replace `(*p)++` and `(*p)--` with `++*p` and `--*p`. Thanks to Bubbler

Comment: `(*p)++;` and `(*p)--;` can be written as `++*p;` and `--*p;`.

Comment: Nice first answer.

Comment: Suggest `*p*=read(0,p,1)` instead of `read(0,p,1)||(*p=0)`

Comment: Also, forgot to welcome you to CGCC!