# Make a Brainfuck Interpreter

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, brainfuck

There [already is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84/107299) a Brainfuck interpreter question, but it is from 2011 and not up to date with current site standards and vague in places. I have [proposed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/repost-interpret-bf) reposting this in chat, and it was well-received. Here goes.

### Objective

Given the Brainfuck code and the program's input as input, run the Brainfuck code. As there are various variants of Brainfuck, here is the one I will use for the challenge:

- There are least 128 cells.
- Cell values are positive integers, having a maximum value of at least 128.
- Going into negative cells in undefined.
- Going into negative numbers is undefined.
- Going above the maximum cell value is undefined.
- Going above the maximum cell is undefined.
- EOF is 0

You may assume that the code will conform to the above constraints and that brackets will be balanced. You may also assume that all input code will be nothing but `<>,.+-[]`.

## Testcases

```
"+[+[<<<+>>>>]+<-<-<<<+<++]<<.<++.<++..+++.<<++.<---.>>.>.+++.------.>-.>>--." -> "Hello, World!"

",[.,]", "abc" -> "abc"
```

## Scoring

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: How should going over the maximum value be treated?

Comment: @CommandMaster implementation defined. That's why I said "at least 128"

Comment: that explains how much the maximum needs to be, not what we should do if the program attempts to exceed it. you spelled out all the other "undefined" things, you may as well add that too :-)

Comment: @thejonymyster true. Edited.

Comment: The 2nd test case seems to be incorrect. `,[,.]` will skip the first character, because it is reading twice. It should be `,[.,]`, which reads the input, and while there's something, it will output and read the input after.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel woops. my BF is not the best :P

Comment: Maybe link to a brainfuck specification?

Comment: You say "going into negative numbers is undefined" but the hello world depends on a wrapping implementation for overflow

Comment: I also noticed what @mousetail said. It was a pain to implement thanks to that. The provided example won't work unless the "tape" pointer overflows to the end. "Going into negative cells [...]" is impossible if we expect the correct output from that example.

Comment: @mousetail oh, it does? I just copied the shortest BF example. will fix

Comment: I don't think this adds anything to the original challenge, as most brainfuck programs are written for a cell size of unsigned 256 and won't work elsewhere. The original "interpret brainfuck" is not overly strict, it simply asks to interpret the variant of brainfuck which most people use. Additionally, the original has many good and interesting answers which this question will almost certainly never accumulate.

Comment: @emanresuA the other one also does not specify EOF, and has strict I/O rules

Comment: @emanresuA "Array size: 30000 bytes (not circled)" <-- This means that trying to go to cell 30001 will do nothing, on the other post. On this one, you're expected to from 30000 to 0, when you try to access 30001. This is a HUGE difference. EOL being 0 is also a HUGE difference. The other one also requires you to handle comments, while this lets you assume that there's no comments. (Newlines are considered comments.) These are REALLY HUGE differences. I doubt that that many answers can be re-posted without some work.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I agree. However, it's not clear to me from the spec of this question that you're expected to go from cell 30000 to cell 0 when you try to access cell 30001. Seggan, would you please clarify?

Comment: @DLosc You're right. I put my foot on my mouth. The example that was posted before, for the "Hello, World!" program, required that you circled back from 0 to the last cell position. This needs clarification.

Comment: @DLosc going past the max cell limit is undefined. is the question not clear on that?

Comment: cc: @IsmaelMiguel ^

Comment: Yes, that is completely missing, since you only mention that "negative cells [are] undefined". Going past the 128th cell doesn't mean it is a negative cell. The next cell can be the 129th cell (no overflow at 128) or the 0th (cyclic "tape", with overflow to positive) cell or the -127th (cyclic tape, with overflow into negative).  You do have "Going above the maximum cell value is undefined", but that's for the cell value, not the pointer value. However, a few lines above, you said the cell values must be integers. The spec does need some tightening.

Comment: I think the spec is far too loose and unopinionated. Maybe there's room for another BF challenge, but IMO it should change things in some meaningful way, like unbounded cells + tape or following the spec precisely. As it is now this challenge is just a downgrade from the existing one in every way except the I/O, which nobody really pays attention to anyway. It also should've been sandboxed for longer, as challenges go this is a pretty poorly specified one. Also, typical practice is to ask on meta before redoing an old challenge, something which should definitely have been done here.

Answer (score 2):

## simply, 425 bytes

This big boy defines an anonymous function which takes an input string and returns the output of the Brainfuck program.

This anonymous function has to be stored into a variable, and receives the code as the 1st argument (`$C`), and the input as the 2nd argument (`$T`).

This is a language being interpreted by JavaScript, which then interprets Brainfuck to generate JavaScript code.

```
fn($C$I){if run&empty($I)$I=''$T=&json_decode(<<<J
{".":"O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);",",":"T[P]=I[0]?I.shift().charCodeAt(0):0;","<":"P=P?P-1:255;",">":"P=(P+1)%256;","-":"T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;","+":"T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;","[":"while(T[P]){","]":"}"}
J)$N=''each$X in$C if$T[$X]$N=&str_concat($N$T[$X])$F=run$argv->map->constructor('X'run&str_concat("var I=Array.from(X+''),O='',T=[],P=0;"$N"return O"))send run$F($I);}
```

It is an absolute mess!

### Ungolfed - to plain English

```
Set $fn to the anonymous function($code, $input) {
    If call &empty($input) then {
        Set $input to "".
    }

    Set $tokens to the result of calling &json_decode(<<<JSON
{
    ".": "output += String.fromCharCode(tape[pointer]);",
    ",": "tape[pointer] = input.length ? input.shift().charCodeAt(0) : 0;",
    "<": "pointer = pointer ? pointer - 1 : 255;",
    ">": "pointer = (pointer + 1) % 256;",
    "-": "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] ? tape[pointer] - 1 : 255;",
    "+": "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] ? (tape[pointer] + 1) % 256 : 1;",
    "[": "while(tape[pointer]){",
    "]": "}"
}
JSON);
    
    Set $inner_code to "".
    Foreach $char in $code {
        If $tokens[$char] then {
            Set $inner_code to the result of calling &str_concat($inner_code, $tokens[$char], "\n").
        }
    }
    
    Set $js_code to the result of calling &str_concat(
        "input = Array.from(input + '');\nvar output = '';\nvar tape = [];\nvar pointer = 0;\n",
        $inner_code,
        "return output;"
    ).
    
    Set $fn to the result of calling $argv["map"]["constructor"]("input", $js_code).
    
    Return the result of calling $fn($input).
}
```

Now it is a lot more readable!

---

### How does it work?

This will simply read the input code, character by character, and replace the valid tokens into JavaScript code.

Using the `array["filter"]["constructor"](code)` (but using `"map"` to save bytes) trick in [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/), I can receive a JavaScript function which I can execute normally!

This is **FAAAAAAAAAAAAR** from the intended way of doing things, but ... it works!

---

### Example output

This is the *JavaScript* code generated for the test cases.

Hello world: `+[+[<<<+>>>>]+<-<-<<<+<++]<<.<++.<++..+++.<<++.<---.>>.>.+++.------.>-.>>--.`

```js
var fn = function anonymous(X
) {
var I=Array.from(X+''),O='',T=[],P=0;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;while(T[P]){T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;while(T[P]){P=P?P-1:255;P=P?P-1:255;P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;P=(P+1)%256;P=(P+1)%256;P=(P+1)%256;P=(P+1)%256;}T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;P=P?P-1:255;P=P?P-1:255;P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;}P=P?P-1:255;P=P?P-1:255;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);P=P?P-1:255;P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);P=P?P-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);P=(P+1)%256;P=(P+1)%256;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);P=(P+1)%256;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;T[P]=T[P]?(T[P]+1)%256:1;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);P=(P+1)%256;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);P=(P+1)%256;P=(P+1)%256;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;T[P]=T[P]?T[P]-1:255;O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);return O
};

console.log(fn());
```

Cat program: `,[.,]`

```js
var fn = function anonymous(X
) {
var I=Array.from(X+''),O='',T=[],P=0;T[P]=I[0]?I.shift().charCodeAt(0):0;while(T[P]){O+=String.fromCharCode(T[P]);T[P]=I[0]?I.shift().charCodeAt(0):0;}return O
};

console.log(fn(prompt("What does the cat say?", "")));
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `brainfuck`, 13 bytes

```
run-brainfuck
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7GqlkFSUmJmXVpqczcWlpB2tHW1jY6NtBwSx2ja6QAjk2Whrx9rY6AEpMNbTBjHAPF1dXT07Oz07sJAuGOjZgYSAtBLX/6LSPF248f//AwA)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7GqlkFSUmJmXVpqczcWlpBOtpxOrxPW/qDRPFy7@/79SYlKyEgA) (with input)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org) + `-C overflow-checks=off`, 370 bytes

```
|p:&[u8]|{let(mut o,mut c,mut t,mut k)=(0,0,[0;128],0);loop{match p[o]{62=>c+=1,60=>c-=1,43=>t[c]+=1,45=>t[c]-=1,46=>print!("{}",t[c]as char),44=>t[c]=stdin().bytes().next().unwrap_or(Ok(0)).unwrap(),91=>if t[c]<1{k=1;while k>0{o+=1;if p[o]==91{k+=1};if p[o]==93{k-=1}}},93=>if t[c]>0{k=1;while k>0{o-=1;if p[o]==91{k-=1}if p[o]==93{k+=1}}},_=>()}o+=1}};use std::io::*;
```

[Attempt This Online! (Hello World)](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVFBjtMwFBXbnsJkgWxqW8m0VG0Se8MB2LGJoirjcWiUNI4ch4IyOQkbJOAALFhyEDjNfCedEcyX_P_z-3nP386X73bo3e8sYG8DigLzUduyMRemTlrVvTBlGeQ_yxadi6rFBI2NdqgUPwZXsv3fF_a-i19lwz6_9w18Hhwy1Gc1Zzfnmggc0pBmYRLd7HMakqQxphvPhVMn1GUmH3c3Qqq1iOguBMAAbDdCukzlnty-WfDM74TsbNW6lzgYp4B6vuiROhWW0O12-VD07s6Py28_O91DbfUnB2VoL7bojsbidzUOySOBCT1EQlYl8uI0GmsRJZdT1WhUy3A0MEMCTT-pEAdoAzH9w2zGGkabpokeNk82IHxmw57beNF_LuvF5SgkJpOZd8nQawTXiePKxPHrZLU8_Z9f_kd01nywxRkJFKyvkcnH7MGyUgiWS0CSSbnO0txvJZeMMX7VcQ84kCnj6YzZHNcCAJQc_HiQrFYlvh799MLKNI1WLo7T91pBHvYSLsGL_tg3ldKYEJBNy_BfvxW3aoEP)

[Attempt This Online (Cat)](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVFLTsMwFBTbnsJkgWzqVEkbqjSps-EAsGITRVVqHBLl48hxKCjNSdggAQfgABwEToOdQAXdzHue5xnNs59eRdvIj9AwLw0MDH7PRFLwnUlTRvOG8CQxovekAmWcVRCBrmASJOStlYnpfp2Ife2dha0b7fUAlq0EHGukA8oBc0SghS0cWr49dyNsIb_gvO7KWNIU1CGPuuWcBHRKbLy0VGOqxlmQQIY00qRzMfYDvyRBLbJKnkKj6w2s-bgBNI0Fwo4zXiSNvNVxZ9tHyRpVK_YgVWmrnYjrDRfwKocW-iUgwiubBFkCtHhtdzmx_V2aFQzkgdVxlcFXQ52UkJUaK6L_wyy6XEXr-x6vFgcbJTyyMY9ttOify3R02ZAAop4PJ79tGFDreF7GPe_cn4xP_3mtP6IW_E7EJSDAwOEMR4Y_mSTwhz0sT3lRMCo9b33DqMLWDZT_LG42TZFRBhFSsn70fX6Jt3RsvwE)

Will crash when it reaches the end of the program.